# Get particular string from url in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating app using angularjs. I need particular string from url,here is my url:

```
https://localhost:8443/#/admin/dashboard
```

I need only admin from url

```
console.log($location.path())// this will gives me `/admin/dashboard`
```

Comment: `console.log($location.path().split('/')[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pasting @AvinashRaj comment as an answer.

Try these basic string methods for your result.

```
$location.path().split('/')[1];
```

**OR**

```
$location.path().slice(1,6);
$location.path().substr(1,5);
```